# Java and C++ communication via Message Queue using JNA/JNI

Tags: java-native-interface

I am trying to create an application in JAVA that could communicate with an existing C++ application via message queue in LINUX.
I have tried JNI using SWIG but it seems SWIG doesn't support C++ as for C it is working fine but for C++ it is throwing some error which on analysis over web shows its incapability for C++.

```
factorial.cpp

#include "factorial.h"

int fact(int  n) {

if(n == 0) return 1;
return n * fact(n-1);
}
```

factorial.h

```
extern "C" {
int fact(int n);
}
```

factorial.i

```
%module factorial
%{
#include "factorial.h"
%}

 int fact(int n);
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

static
{
    System.loadLibrary("factorial");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result = factorial.fact(5);
    System.out.println(result);
}
}
```

Then command for generating .java files is
1: swig -c++ -java factorial.i

and then commands for compilation of factorial.cpp and factorial_wrap.cxx files are:

1: g++ -c -fpic factorial.cpp

2: g++ -c -fpic factorial_wrap.cxx -I /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/include -I /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/include/linux

then command for making libfactorial.so

1: ld -G factorial.o factorial_wrap.o -o libfactorial.so

then to compile Main.java:

1: javac Main.java

2: java Main

then i am facing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: factorialJNI.fact(I)I
at factorialJNI.fact(Native Method)
at factorial.fact(factorial.java:12)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Any other possible solution for same?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "throwing some error"? What error?  Post the error if you want help.  Post your code also.

Comment: _"but it seems SWIG doesn't support C++"_. The documentation [suggests otherwise](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html).